# Failed to transform file 'pp-release.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform IdentityTransform

Tags: java, android, gradle, aar

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to transform file 'pp-release.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform IdentityTransform

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me by following below steps

1. clean your project
2. rebuild it again
3. update build.gradle version (if dialog box appear and informed to update).
4. and rebuild it again.
5. Done.

Comment: Obs.: Invalidate Caches / Restart **did not work**, but this solution did. Thanks, @nilesh! :D