# Gradle error: Failed to transform file to match attributes jetified

Tags: android, gradle, azure-pipelines

I have set up a pipeline that runs my tests in microsoft [azure pipelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/services/devops/pipelines/). On my local machine this works fine and the `jetified-libidpmobile-debug.jar` file is found in the gradle system directory on my machine:

```
/Users/jimclermonts/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/efad9765ab457848824459e0c76abddc/jetified-libidpmobile-debug.jar
```

this is my `build.gradle`:

```
debugImplementation files('libs/libidpmobile-debug.jar')
```

From what I understand, `jetified-libidpmobile-debug.jar` is automatically created by [jetifier](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) from the `libidpmobile-debug.jar` file.

Output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_classStructurekaptDebugKotlin'.
   > Failed to transform file 'jetified-libidpmobile-debug.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=class-structure, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}
      > Execution failed for StructureArtifactTransform: /Users/iosadmin/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/1e14bb7ec832a0c2c967e6c977ddd9b9/jetified-libidpmobile-debug.jar.
         > error in opening zip file
```

Here is the part of my azure-pipelines.yml that assembles the debug and tests the unit tests:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: Mobile-Pool

steps:
- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: ''
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx4096m'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'assembleDebug testDebugUnitTest'
```

I tried the solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45138391/failed-to-transform-file-45907c80e09917e1b776adf038505958-to-match-attributes), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376219/failed-to-transform-file-pp-release-aar-to-match-attributes-artifacttype-proc) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268865/android-x-toolsreplace-specified-at-line-for-attribute-but-no-new-value-spec) with no result.
The jar file is 4mb big and is the only file that is in the code repository instead of some maven repository.

Updated Gradle to the latest:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-beta05'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

Tried to edit the androidmanifest like this:

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory">
```

**build.gradle:**

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: Do you have `android.enableJetifier=true` in your build server's gradle.properties?

Answer (score 1):

I used `jetifier-standalone` to jetify the files. Added it to `gradle.properties`:

```
android.jetifier.blacklist = libidpmobile
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the databinding issue from the error `The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[android.databinding.minApi....`

You can try adding below line to build.gradle file.

`kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradle_version"`

You can check out below similar threads for more information:

[Android Databinding build fail after Gradle plugin update with migration to annotationProcessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165752/android-databinding-build-fail-after-gradle-plugin-update-with-migration-to-anno)

[Fail make project if android data binding enabled](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/313)

Hope above helps!

Comment: I already have this:    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    } I think the problem is with jetifying certain jar files. And this is not succeeding on the CI, but on my local machine it works fine.

Comment: I see now that the error message has changed. But not after adding the databinding library.

Comment: Could it be because the java jdk used in cloud agent is different with your local machine? You can try setting the `jdkVersionOption` for gradle task to make sure the environment in the clould agent is the same with your local machine.

Comment: Java 1.8 is used